# Optimizing a slow django queryset from a large and growing dataset

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a page that loads way too slow.  Somehow I need to improve the way it's data is queried (caching? partial load/pages? etc.)

Note I am a django noob and haven't quite wrapped my head around `model.Manager` and and `models.query.QuerySet` so if this setup looks awkward....

Currently, the page is taking about 18 seconds to load the queryset, and it currently only has about 500 records.  There will be on average about 100 new records a day.

[image: Network stats]

The database is Postgresql

The slow **view**:

```
def approvals(request):
    ...
    approved_submissions = QuestSubmission.objects.all_approved()
    ...
```

The slow **queryset**:

```
class QuestSubmissionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    ...

    def approved(self):
        return self.filter(is_approved=True)

    def completed(self):
         return self.filter(is_completed=True).order_by('-time_completed')

    ...

class QuestSubmissionManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return QuestSubmissionQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all_approved(self, user=None):
        return self.get_queryset().approved().completed()

    ...
```

Resulting SQL from `QuestSubmission.objects.all_approved()`:

```
'SELECT "quest_manager_questsubmission"."id", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."quest_id", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."user_id", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."ordinal", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."is_completed", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."time_completed", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."is_approved", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."time_approved", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."timestamp", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."updated", "quest_manager_questsubmission"."game_lab_transfer" FROM "quest_manager_questsubmission" WHERE ("quest_manager_questsubmission"."is_approved" = True AND "quest_manager_questsubmission"."is_completed" = True) ORDER BY "quest_manager_questsubmission"."time_completed" DESC'
```

The slow **model**:

```
class QuestSubmission(models.Model):
    quest = models.ForeignKey(Quest)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="quest_submission_user")
    ordinal = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 1, help_text = 'indicating submissions beyond the first for repeatable quests')
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_approved = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    game_lab_transfer = models.BooleanField(default = False, help_text = 'XP not counted')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["time_approved", "time_completed"]

    objects = QuestSubmissionManager()

    #other methods
    ....
```

What strategies are available to fix this? I tried using django's Paginator, but it only seems to display in pages, but it still loads the entire queryset.

Comment: Did you try to do `manage.py shell` and `str(QuestSubmission.objects.all_approved().query())` to see what SQL it actually generates? Otherwise the code looks normal and the problem can be elsewhere.

Comment: I get: `TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable`

Comment: Ow, sorry, it should be just `str(QuestSubmission.objects.all_approved().query)`

Comment: Your browser timings don't really tell you where the bottleneck is on the server. Can you try adding [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/) which will break down the server-side execution time and also show you what queries are hitting the DB.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing to look at:

- Is this query slow because it is returning a very large result set?

or

- Is this query slow because it's taking a while to filter down the table?

Assuming the former, you don't have a lot of good options besides "return less data".

If it's the latter, you should probably run an `EXPLAIN` on the database, but right off the bat I'd say you probably want an index, possibly on `(is_approved, is_completed)`. Which can be done with:

```
class Meta:
    index_together = [
        ["is_completed", "is_approved"],
    ]
```

Comment: is there a way to check if it is either of these?

Answer (score 4):

If you are showing the related objects in your page try to use the
[select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

> Without select_related(), this would make a database query for each
>    loop iteration in order to fetch the related blog for each entry.

Comment: I think this might be it.  I tried running the query in  the shell and it returned instantly.  The template is going for approved_submissions.quest.etc and approved_submissions.user.etc quite a bit. Investigating....

Comment: doh, I'm an idtiot.  It was fast because I tried it on my dev server which has no data...

Comment: @43Tesseracts this should be an issue because you are iterating over related records. Just remember that it will execute a db query before for each relation for each record... will just grow a lot!. Try enabling debug_toolbar to know more details about whats happening on the server.

Answer (score 4):

I would construct a base queryset to build upon and apply the filters needed:

```
def approvals(request):
    ...
    approved_submissions = QuestSubmission.objects.select_related('quest', 'user').all_approved()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a browser issue rather than a database issue. With Django pagination you can select one page at a time and lower the load on database as well as the browser: [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/)

Comment: I don't see anywhere there that lowers the load on the database? In the example they are still loading the entire queryset: `contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()`.  However, if the performance problem is due to hits on related data in the template as suggested by Paulo P, then it should work right?

Comment: Why do you think it's the browser?  I thought the green line (17.71 s) was django loading the view/template?

Comment: Yes but that also includes rendering of the page in browser. When you use pagination you only select 20 (if your page size is 20) records at a time and you get a faster response from database. Another important performance issue is when your dataset is large Django ORM has to convert every item read from the database to model objects.